# The namespace name Infrastructure does not exist in a namespace system.data.entity

Tags: .net

I am getting an error message when using infrastructure namespace in system.data.entity namespace

Comment: Please include the error message in your question body, not just the title.

Comment: Is this issue coming from the entity framework, mvc or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the .NET assembly `System.Data.Entity.dll`.

Comment: If the reference is selected in the Reference Manager and the error persists, what is a good next step? I am having the same problem and posted a similar question with additional detail here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22796205/visual-studio-2012-mvc-build-error-the-type-or-namespace-name-infrastructure]

Answer (score 18):

You also need a reference to the EntityFramework, or you will get the same error.

Comment: I [had the same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22796205/visual-studio-2012-mvc-build-error-the-type-or-namespace-name-infrastructure) and EntityFramework was the culprit. But simply installing the package through the NuGet Package Manager was not enough. I had to then use the Reference Manager to manually Browse to the EntityFramework.dll.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem.  I made a reference to `System.Data.Entity` but it was complaining about `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure`.  The solution was to add the [EntityFramework nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework).  Once it's installed it actually removes the original `System.Data.Entity` reference and points to a new DLL that includes `System.Data.Entity` and `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure`.