# Visual Studio 2012 MVC build error: The type or namespace name 'Infrastructure' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data.Entity'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, build

**Update:** The assembly reference to *System.Data.Entity* is selected in the Reference Manager.

### The Setup

I get an error when trying to run an out-of-the-box ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application. I made no modifications.

I simply chose *File > New Project > Visual C# > ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application* and left all the default settings intact.

Under *Project Settings*, I chose *Internet Application* for the template, *Razor* for the view engine, and checked *Use HTML5 semantic markup*.

I then immediately chose *Build > Build Solution* which fails and produces this error and five other warnings (shown in the screenshot).

### The Error

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'Infrastructure' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data.Entity' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>
> C:\Users\johndoe\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\Global.asax.cs

### Yes, I know...

...[this question has been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577157/the-namespace-name-infrastructure-does-not-exist-in-a-namespace-system-data-enti) — [many times](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=The+type+or+namespace+name+does+not+exist+in+the+namespace) — but the answers on those posts do not provide adequate information to solve my problem.

***Please, be specific in your response***, with step-by-step instructions, as I am new to Visual Studio and its MVC app development framework.

### The Question

**What would cause Visual Studio not to work right out-of-the-box?** This is a fresh install. Is there an update that could have caused this issue or could fix this issue?

### The Screenshot

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio Error List]

### System Information

Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012
Version 11.0.61030.00 Update 4

Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.50709

**Installed products:**

- Architecture and Modeling Tools
- LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2012
- Office Developer Tools
- Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2012
- Visual Basic 2012
- Visual C# 2012
- Visual C++ 2012
- Visual F# 2012
- Visual Studio 2012 Code Analysis Spell Checker
- Visual Studio 2012 SharePoint Developer Tools
- ASP.NET and Web Tools
- LNDevEnv
- NuGet Package Manager
- PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer
- SQL Server Data Tools

Comment: possible duplicate of [The namespace name Infrastructure does not exist in a namespace system.data.entity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577157/the-namespace-name-infrastructure-does-not-exist-in-a-namespace-system-data-enti)

Comment: @tnw See the section above titled "Yes, I know..."

Comment: I saw it. Is the problem in the question I linked not exactly the same as yours?

Comment: @tnw See the section above that reads "...but the answers on those posts do not provide adequate information to solve my problem."

Comment: The problem is exactly the same, but the solution is vague and unhelpful. See the section above that reads "Please, be specific in your response, with step-by-step instructions..."

Comment: I linked to a Stackoverflow search to indicate that I realized this question has been asked many times in many ways. I did find the exact one you linked to in that search, but it was not helpful. I will amend my post to clarify that.

Comment: *How* wasn't it helpful? You are going to get the exact same answer here. Are you having trouble adding the assembly reference??

Comment: @tnw "Please, be specific in your response, with step-by-step instructions..." and please remove your down vote. This question is impeccably explained, well-formatted, and shows and intent to find the answer elsewhere.

Comment: No, your question is a duplicate and will remain marked as such. Step by step instructions on how to add an assembly reference are out there if you'd just look for it. Took me about 10 seconds to find the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(VS.100).aspx AGAIN, what exactly are you having trouble with? Have you added a reference to the assembly in the question I linked??

Comment: @tnw Thanks for the link. That doesn't solve the problem. My question remains unanswered and while the question is the same as the one you linked to as a duplicate, the solution may be different for my scenario. It is perfectly appropriate for me to ask, to provide additional details, and seek a detailed answer. Please provide a solution or remove yourself from this thread. You're being unconstructive.

Comment: I'm trying to help you but if you won't answer questions that I've repeatedly asked that, if answered, would help get your question answered and also make your question not a duplicate, you are the one being nonconstructive.

Comment: @tnw I'm unsure how to respond to that. I have answered all of your questions and provided extensive detail. I have updated my question to indicate that I tried the solution in the supposed duplicate and it did not solve the problem. I have ensured that the assembly is selected in the Reference Manager, yet the error persists.

Comment: See my answer now that you've answered my questions.

Comment: Note I just followed the exact steps you outlined in VS2012 and had no compile errors. I am on Premium 2012, version 4.5.50709

Comment: @tnw I am on VS Ultimate 2012 11.0.61030.00 Update 4

Comment: @tnw I added system information added to the bottom of original post above in hopes that it helps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem and resolved it by adding a reference to Entity Framework.
This is done by right clicking "Reference" in Solution Explorer and selecting "Add Reference" Next browse to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE.  Choose EntityFramework.dll.

Comment: I discovered this step and left a [similar comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22796205/visual-studio-2012-mvc-build-error-the-type-or-namespace-name-infrastructure/30869733#comment34794589_22796689) on another answer.

Answer (score 4):

On the ribbon, select the dropdown that says "Debug" and select Configuration Manager. From there, select the dropdown under "Platform", click New, and now under New platform select x86. Hit ok and close the configuration manager. Try building your project.

System.data.entity is a 32-bit assembly so you may have to build your project as x86. If this doesn't work, you can follow the same steps above and select x64 and try again.

AFAIK you shouldn't have to do this, I followed your steps excatly and had no issues building under Any CPU.

You can also try installing entityframework. Right click on references, manage nuget packages, click online and you should see EntityFramework come up in the center column.

Comment: From the Configuration Manager, I tried changing the Platform to x86 and then to x64, but neither fixed the issue. (Note: I found it under the "Build", not "Debug" menu.)

Comment: Installed the EntityFramework through NuGet, and that changed the error.

Comment: Error: The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Note: The original error no longer appears.

Comment: However, I am getting new warnings too. Warning: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "EntityFramework". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

Comment: @gfullam Change the build back to Any CPU and see where that leaves you.

Comment: I'm at a loss. Any ideas? Could it have anything to do with the installation or other configuration in Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because EntityFramework is the culprit, but simply installing the package through the NuGet Package Manager was not enough. I had to then use the Reference Manager to manually Browse to the EntityFramework.dll. As a test, I created subsequent new projects and found that I had to manually Browse to the .dll for every new project. I'm going to have to ask a new question in a separate post about why the EntityFramework reference is always broken for my new projects even though it is installed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @gfullam Sometimes those references can break, glad to see that installing EntityFramework got you going in the right direction at least.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem in MVC 4 (should be similar in MVC 3), here's what fixed it for me:

- Expand your References in project explorer and click on the assembly reference (System.Data.Entity and any other assembly reference used out of the box will be in here)
- In the Properties window change the property Copy Local to "True"
- Repeat the above two steps for all assembly references that are included but are throwing build errors

Running an out of the box MVC 3/4 application should work after you've done this.

Answer (score 1):

This solution may work for you if changing the build settings to x86 causes build errors locally.

We got the same error, the issue for us was a previous version of Entity Framework had leftover references that were no longer needed but still causing build errors. We were not getting build issue locally but when trying to build on TeamCity then the error would present itself.

Using Package Manager Console we ran `Update-Package EntityFramework -Reinstall` and this removed the reference for us.

Answer (score 0):

Using visual studio 2012, I am able to resolve this issue by adding reference by browsing to path:-
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\NuGet Packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\lib\net45

and then choosing the entity framework.dll