# EntityFramework package version="6.1.3" and Web config version 6.0.0.0?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I created a ASP.NET project which included EF 6.1.3

Its show package version="6.1.3" and in  Web.config version 6.0.0.0

However in web.config i still have this:

```
section name="entityFramework" 
type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, 
EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"
```

All other dependent assemblies are updated correctly.

Its gives an error on server

> The type or namespace name 'Infrastructure' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System.Data.Entity

I thought this is due to version problem. Should I have updated this myself?

Comment: Does your web.config file have an assembly redirect for entityframework?

Answer (score 2):

Version 6.1.3 that you download through NuGet has an actual product version of 6.0.0, they are the same thing.
[See Microsoft Download Centre](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762)

Your error with namespace 'infrastructure' is [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577157/the-namespace-name-infrastructure-does-not-exist-in-a-namespace-system-data-enti) and could just need a reference to System.Data.Entity.dll

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the reference to `System.Data.Entity.dll` in your project. Also try to add EntityFramework.dll by browsing it to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE and then choose `EntityFramework.dll`.

Comment: I add the reference  of System.Data.Entity in my project and reinstall EF 6.1.3 but its gives the same error on server.
Do i change the EF Version to lower like 6.1.0 or 6.0.0?