# Entity Framework Version=6.0.0.0 error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, web-config

I installed entity framework version 6.1.3 . I have an Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral error.

My config file is :

```
    <configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <pages validateRequest="false" enableEventValidation="false" enableViewStateMac="false"  viewStateEncryptionMode="Never" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B11D50A3"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7A93408"/>
        <add assembly="System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=03F1D5A3"/>
        <add assembly="PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1BF564E3"/>
        <add assembly="System.Speech, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1BF3D3E3"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime/>
    <!--<compilation debug="true"/>-->
  </system.web>
```

How do i fix an error?

Comment: Check your packages folder. Do you have EntityFramework.6.1.3 under there with a copy of EntityFramework.dll in the lib\net45 folder? If not, reinstall EF from Nuget.

Comment: I check it. I have a package. Project is running local but not running server. Please help

Comment: Is the EntityFramework.dll in the /bin folder of server? Are you using a build server like teamcity? This is probably more of a Nuget issue. Take a look at Nuget package restore. http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/01/the-right-way-to-restore-nuget-packages.html

Comment: Yes entityframework.dll in the /bin folder of server. I tried but not running.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
```

has a version number of 6.0.0.0. Change it to 6.1.3.0

Comment: No, 6.1.3 has the same product version 6.0.0 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948838/entityframework-package-version-6-1-3-and-web-config-version-6-0-0-0