# How to resolve Errors of below code?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, dbcontext

How to resolve Errors of below code?

### Code

```
namespace Phonebook
{
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
14- using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;


17-  public partial class ContactsEntities : DbContext
{
    public ContactsEntities()
 20-       : base("name=ContactsEntities")
    {
    }

 24- protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Tbl_Contacts> Tbl_Contacts { get; set; }

    public class DbSet<T>
    {
        internal object Tolist;
    }
} 
}
```

### Errors

> Error CS0115 'ContactsEntities.OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder)': no
>   suitable method found to override Phonebook
>   C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Phonebook\ Phonebook \ModelContacts.Context.cs 24
>
> Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Infrastructure' does not
>   exist in the namespace 'System.Data.Entity' (are you missing an
>   assembly reference?) Phonebook C:\Users\PC\Desktop\ Phonebook \
>   Phonebook \ModelContacts.Context.cs 14
>
> Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'DbModelBuilder' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   Phonebook C:\Users\PC\Desktop\
>   Phonebook\Phonebook\ModelContacts.Context.cs 24
>
> Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'DbContext' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   Phonebook C:\Users\PC\Desktop\ Phonebook\ Phonebook
>   \ModelContacts.Context.cs 17
>
> Error CS1729 'DbContext' does not contain a constructor that takes 1
>   arguments Phonebook C:\Users\PC\Desktop\ Phonebook \Phonebook
>   \ModelContacts.Context.cs 20

Comment: Hi, could you please try and give us a little more context about what's going on here?

Comment: Have you... included the reference in your project?

Comment: A Google search of your error at line 14 gives a lot of apparently useful results. For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577157/the-namespace-name-infrastructure-does-not-exist-in-a-namespace-system-data-enti).

Comment: You should have EntityFramework included in the list that you get in VS solution explorer under references in you project. The messages are telling you that it is not there, or not installed properly.

Comment: Right click on the project name and select Manage Nuget packages from the menu. Type EntityFramework in the search box and install it.

Comment: Thanks!
My problem has been resolved of Your soulotion But Was needed I make the 'Powershell' settings through on the 'ControlPanel'.@PhilipSmith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem has been resolved :

I added EntityFramework to project from Nuget packages in visualStudio and I Performed ' Powershell ' settings in control panel .